# Converts number in text format function code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, numbers-to-words

I have created a function which converts numbers into text format and successfully converted up to 6 digit numbers. However, I want to know if I can make any modifications to make the code shorter.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var onesVal = ['Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine'];
  var twoVal = ['Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen', 'Fifteen', 'Sixteen', 'Seventeen', 'Eighteen', 'Ninteen'];
  var tensVal = ["", "", 'Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Fourty', 'Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninty'];
  var powersVal = ['Hundred', 'Thousand', 'Lakh'];

  $('input').on('input propertychange', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $('p').text('');
    } else {
      //var textVal = $(this).val();
      var textVal = parseInt($(this).val());
      if (textVal < 10) {
        $('p').text(onesVal[textVal]);
      } else if (textVal < 100) {
        var getTwoVal = forTwoValue(textVal);
        $('p').text(getTwoVal);
      } else if (textVal < 1000) {
        var getThreeVal = forThreeValue(textVal);
        $('p').text(getThreeVal);
      } else if (textVal < 10000) {
        var getFourVal = forFourValue(textVal);
        $('p').text(getFourVal);
      } else if (textVal < 100000) {
        var getFiveVal = forFiveValue(textVal);
        $('p').text(getFiveVal);
      } else if (textVal < 1000000) {
        var getSixVal = forSixValue(textVal);
        $('p').text(getSixVal);
      };
    };
  });

  function forTwoValue(value) {
    value = value.toString();
    if (value < 20) {
      return twoVal[value[1]];
    } else if (value % 10 == 0) {
      return tensVal[value[0]];
    } else {
      return tensVal[value[0]] + ' ' + onesVal[value[1]];
    };
  };

  function forThreeValue(value) {
    value = value.toString();
    if (value % 100 == 0) {
      return onesVal[value[0]] + ' ' + powersVal[0];
    } else {
      var hundOne = Math.floor(value / 100);
      var hundTwo = (value % 100).toString();
      if (hundTwo < 10) {
        return onesVal[hundOne] + ' ' + powersVal[0] + ' ' + onesVal[hundTwo];
      } else if (hundTwo < 100) {
        var getTwoVal = forTwoValue(hundTwo);
        return onesVal[hundOne] + ' ' + powersVal[0] + ' ' + getTwoVal;
      };
    };
  };

  function forFourValue(value) {
    value = value.toString();
    if (value % 1000 == 0) {
      return onesVal[value[0]] + ' ' + powersVal[1];
    } else {
      var thouOne = Math.floor(value / 1000);
      var thouTwo = (value % 1000).toString();
      if (thouTwo < 10) {
        return onesVal[thouOne] + ' ' + powersVal[1] + ' ' + onesVal[thouTwo];
      } else if (thouTwo < 100) {
        var getTwoVal = forTwoValue(thouTwo);
        return onesVal[thouOne] + ' ' + powersVal[0] + ' ' + getTwoVal;
      } else if (thouTwo < 1000) {
        var getThreeVal = forThreeValue(thouTwo);
        return onesVal[thouOne] + ' ' + powersVal[1] + ' ' + getThreeVal;
      };
    };
  };

  function forFiveValue(value) {
    value = value.toString();
    var tenThouOne = Math.floor(value / 1000).toString();
    var tenThouTwo = (value % 1000).toString();
    var getTwoVal = forTwoValue(tenThouOne);
    if (tenThouTwo == 0) {
      return getTwoVal + ' ' + powersVal[1];
    } else if (tenThouTwo < 10) {
      return getTwoVal + ' ' + powersVal[1] + ' ' + onesVal[tenThouTwo];
    } else if (tenThouTwo < 100) {
      var getTwoVal2 = forTwoValue(tenThouTwo);
      return getTwoVal + ' ' + powersVal[1] + ' ' + getTwoVal2;
    } else if (tenThouTwo < 1000) {
      var getThreeVal = forThreeValue(tenThouTwo);
      return getTwoVal + ' ' + powersVal[1] + ' ' + getThreeVal;
    };
  };

  function forSixValue(value) {
    value = value.toString();
    if (value % 100000 == 0) {
      return onesVal[value[0]] + ' ' + powersVal[2];
    } else {
      var lakhOne = Math.floor(value / 100000).toString();
      var lakhTwo = (value % 100000).toString();
      if (lakhTwo == 0) {
        return onesVal[lakhOne] + ' ' + powersVal[2];
      } else if (lakhTwo < 10) {
        return onesVal[lakhOne] + ' ' + powersVal[2] + ' ' + onesVal[lakhTwo];
      } else if (lakhTwo < 100) {
        var getTwoVal = forTwoValue(lakhTwo);
        return onesVal[lakhOne] + ' ' + powersVal[2] + ' ' + getTwoVal;
      } else if (lakhTwo < 1000) {
        var getThreeVal = forThreeValue(lakhTwo);
        return onesVal[lakhOne] + ' ' + powersVal[2] + ' ' + getThreeVal;
      } else if (lakhTwo < 10000) {
        var getFourVal = forFourValue(lakhTwo);
        return onesVal[lakhOne] + ' ' + powersVal[2] + ' ' + getFourVal;
      } else if (lakhTwo < 100000) {
        var getFiveVal = forFiveValue(lakhTwo);
        return onesVal[lakhOne] + ' ' + powersVal[2] + ' ' + getFiveVal;
      };
    };
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter Number : <input type="text" maxlength="6">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

A few thoughts:

- The whole logic seems much too hard-coded.  Think about the problem, which is that you basically need to take the string representation of the number and grab a group of the last three characters off the string at a time to process, the whole time tracking the number of "groups" that have been processed to be able to add "thousand", "million", etc. to it.  Think about breaking apart your function along those lines instead of having a bunch of `for*Value` functions.
- You should only have one point in our code where you are writing to the target `p` element after the word string has been built. There is no reason to repeat `('p').text(*);` throughout your code.
- Consider encapsulating all your conversion logic under one function such that your code in the event handler can be greatly simplified and you could re-use this function elsewhere.

For example:

```
$('input').on('input propertychange', function() {
  $('p').text(
    // numberToWords() could be included from another file
    numberToWords($(this).val())
  );
}
```

- In general, I would recommend you getting in the habit of using exact comparisons (`===` and `!==`) instead of loose comparisons as default behavior.  This will make your code less fragile to unexpected truthy/falsey behavior. Use loose comparisons only where you have a specific use case to do so.
- I don't think "zero" needs to be in your array, as this is an edge case that should be handled upfront before the main logic.

Answer (score 1):

- You can combine the first twenty numbers. Instead of doing:

  ```
  if (textVal < 10)
    onesVal[textVal]
  ...
  if (textVal > 10 && textVal < 20) 
    twosVal[textVal]
  ```

  Just create a single array and write

  ```
  if (textVal < 20)
    oneOrTwosVal[textVal]
  ```

  - Group your code into groups of three digits and reuse that so given

    function forThreeValue ...

  You can write

  ```
  if (value >= 1000)
    return forThreeValue(value / 1000) + ' thousand and ' + forThreeValue(value % 1000)
  else
    return forThreeValue(value);
  ```

  (You will have some corner cases for example 1000)

Answer (score 1):

**Numbers to Words**

To me this is a recursive problem. We start by breaking the problem down into numbers in three digit sets.

1a. Terms: We need some way to lookup values, numerically, arrays are perfect for this.

```
const   SUBTWENTY = [ null, 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];
const   DECA = [ null, 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];
```

1b. Larger numbers: any number above 99 has unique names, "hundred", "thousand", "million" etc.

```
const   ILLIONS = [3,4,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,100,101,303];
    ILLIONS.words = {
        3: "hundred",
        4: "thousand",
        6: "million",
        9: "milliard",
        9: "billion",
        12: "trillion",
        15: "quadrillion",
        18: "quintillion",
        21: "sextillion",
        24: "septillion",
        27: "octillion",
        30: "nonillion",
        33: "decillion",
        36: "undecillion",
        39: "duodecillion",
        42: "tredecillion",
        45: "quattuordecillion",
        48: "quindecillion",
        51: "sexdecillion",
        54: "septendecillion",
        57: "octodecillion",
        60: "novemdecillion",
        63: "vigintillion",
        10: "google",
        10: "googlePlex",
        30: "centillion"
    }
```

2. Parsing large numbers, 100 or more.

   Our objective here is to break the number down into 3 digit units.

   We will use our ILLIONS array to lookup our words for the bigger numbers

   We simply go through each of these, ILLIONS[n], largest 
   to smallest.
3. Parsing numbers less than 100;

   // Pseudo Code

   if( number > 20 ){

   ```
   n = ( number / 10 ), ignoring the remainder

   using n, we should be able to find a matching value in the "TENTHS" array;

   NOTE: we are exploiting arrays here, so that the product of our calculation
   (number / 10) will be an index to a value which is the word version of the 
   number we are looking for.

   add that word TENTHS[n] to the words array.

   assign ( number % 10 ) to number variable
   ```

   }

   if( number > 0 ){

   ```
   Essentially the same trick here, except we will 
   lookup number in the LESS_TWENTY array, pushing 
   it's value into the words array
   ```

   }

   if( decimals ){

   ```
   Now we need to address decimals, this is simply a 
   recursive call back to our numbersToWords function, 
   only we tack on "point" and then the results of numbersToWords
   to the words array.
   ```

   }

That's the basic idea, here is some code, with some additional checks, that
does the job nicely.

```js
const  SUBTWENTY = [ null, 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];
const  DECA = [ null, 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];
const  ILLIONS = [3,4,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,100,101,303];
 ILLIONS.words = {3: "hundred",4: "thousand", 6: "million", 9: "milliard", 9: "billion", 12: "trillion", 15: "quadrillion", 18: "quintillion", 21: "sextillion", 24: "septillion", 27: "octillion", 30: "nonillion", 33: "decillion", 36: "undecillion", 39: "duodecillion", 42: "tredecillion", 45: "quattuordecillion", 48: "quindecillion", 51: "sexdecillion", 54: "septendecillion", 57: "octodecillion", 60: "novemdecillion", 63: "vigintillion", 10: "google", 10: "googlePlex", 30: "centillion"}
  

function numbersToWords(num, words, decimal, segments){
  
  words = [], decimal = ((Math.abs(num) % 1) * 100).toFixed() || 0;
  if(num < 0) words.push('negative');
  num = Math.floor(Math.abs(num)).toFixed();
  
  segments = [];
  
  for(var i=ILLIONS.length; i > 0; i--){
    if( ILLIONS[i] <= num.length ) segments.push(ILLIONS[i]);
  }
  
  while(num){ 
    let sub = num.slice(0, Math.max(0, num.length % 3 || 3));
    if(Number(sub) > 0 ) words.push(hundredsToWords(sub), ILLIONS.words[segments.shift()]);
    num = num.slice(num.length % 3 || 3);
  }
  
  if( !!decimal ){
    words.push('point', hundredsToWords(Number(decimal)));
  }

  return words.join(' ').replace('  ', ' ');
   
}

function hundredsToWords(num, words){

  num = String(Math.floor(num).toFixed());
    
  words = [];
  
  if(num.length > 2 ){
    if( num[1] === '0' ){
      words.push(SUBTWENTY[num[0]], ILLIONS.words[num.length]);      
      num = num.slice(2);
    } else {
      words.push(hundredsToWords(num.slice(0,1)), ILLIONS.words[num.length ]);
      num = num.slice(1);
    } 
    if(num[0] !== '0') words.push('and');      
  }
  
  if(num > 20){
    words.push(DECA[num[0]]);
    num = num[1];
  }
  
  if(num > 0 && num < 20) words.push(SUBTWENTY[Number(num)]);
  
  return words.join(' ');
}


console.log(numbersToWords(10234.44));
console.log(numbersToWords(-10234.44));
```

Comment: I like your answer but I think it has a bug, try 100234.  http://codepen.io/imjosh/pen/WjNOqa?editors=1011

Comment: yeah, i would need to track down the error, i believe it's a combination of rounding errors, and issues with lose of precision somewhere.

Comment: fixed it, I reworked a few things, now it will work for numbers upto a centillion

Answer (score 0):

All you really need are two things: first, a function to get you up to a three-digit value. Then, you just go through each thousand, find the 3-digit value for those 3 numbers (i.e. the 1,000's value for 340,000 is Three-Hundred and Forty). Here's the code for it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var onesVal = ['', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen', 'Fifteen', 'Sixteen', 'Seventeen', 'Eighteen', 'Ninteen'];
  var tensVal = ["", "", 'Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Fourty', 'Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninty'];
  var thousandsPowers = ['Thousand', 'Million', 'Billion', 'Trillion', 'Quadrilion'];

  $('input').on('input propertychange', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $('p').text('');
    } else {
      var textVal = parseInt($(this).val()); 
      if (textVal == 0) $('p').text('Zero');
       else {
       var greaterVal = forGreaterValue(textVal); 
        $('p').text(greaterVal);
      }
    };
  });

  function forLowerVal(value) {
    value = value.toString();
    if (value < 20) {
      return onesVal[value];
    } else {
      return tensVal[Math.floor(value/10)] + (value%10 != 0 ? '-' + onesVal[value % 10] : '');
    }
  }
  function forThreeValue(value) {
    value = value.toString();
    if (value < 100) return forLowerVal(value);
    else return onesVal[Math.floor(value/100)] + ' Hundred' + (value % 100 != 0 ? ' and ' + forLowerVal(value % 100) : '');
  };
  
  function forGreaterValue(value) {
    var currentPower = 0;
    var outputString = "";
    outputString += forThreeValue(value%1000);
    value = Math.floor(value/1000);
    while (value > 0) {
      console.log(value);
      outputString = (value%1000 != 0 ? forThreeValue(value%1000) + ' ' + thousandsPowers[currentPower] + ' ' : '') + outputString;
      value = Math.floor(value/1000);
      currentPower += 1;
    }
    return outputString;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter Number : <input type="text">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Just add more after Quadrillion, and it should scale infinitely.